# Remove timestamp in maven tycho build

Tags: maven, tycho

I have a multi module eclipse RCP Application. We are building the application through maven tycho. The build is creating successfully.

In the build folder i have the usual plugins folder which contains all the plugins(both jar packaging and directory packaging) in the project.

The plugins contains timestamp in it.Is there any way to remove the timestamp from the plugin while building. currently it is *plugin.name_1.0.0.20200211.jar* but i want the plugin to be *plugin.name_1.0.0.jar*

Comment: @greg-449 fourth component in jar is fine. But we have some directory packaging which is used for command line generation. Is there any option to disable timestamp. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the `finalName` configuration for the `tycho-packaging-plugin` sets the name and normally uses `${buildQualifier}` for the final part. I don't know what will and won't work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a format tag did the trick for me. Pom file snippet is attached.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tycho-version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <format>''</format>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```